# Why isn't the document going into edit mode

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

I've done this before -- I have a button on a xPage which sets the document into edit mode via a simple action.  In fact, I just copied the 'edit' and 'save' buttons from another app.  But when I click the 'edit' button, the document does not go into edit mode.  I have Manager access so can edit the document.  Not quite sure why it's not going into edit mode.  Any thoughts?

thanks.
clem

Comment: An Authors field would explain that behavior.  Or if you're using a browser, the "Maximum Internet Name and password" (which overrides your Manager access) could be set to Author (or lower.)

Comment: Hi Duston.  I don't have author fields but I added one just in case that would make a difference but it didn't.  Still not sure what's going on.  Thanks, clem

Comment: But are you logged in or accessing the page as Anonymous?  Put &login in your URL to make sure.

Comment: What's the code behind the edit button? Should it be a partial refresh, or a full refresh? In that case, when you click edit, you should be able to see *some* activity on your Developer Tools screen in the browser (assuming this is for a browser). Check also the Console screen in case you have JS errors.

Comment: I'm not an anonymous user, I've logged in as myself. I checked the console and no errors (good tip tho!).  It's set to 'full update'.  The code is just a 'simple action' with 'change document mode' set to 'edit'.

Comment: Can we see some code?

Comment: In regards to "show some code" : Clem stated that the button was calling a "Simple Action". Not much to show then...

Comment: @Clem: some things to try: 1. Have a look at the page's url; if it's open in read mode the query string part should contain "openDocument". Change this to "editDocument" leaving the remainder as it is. Then hit <Enter> reload the page with the altered Param. If this doesn't switch into edit you need to double check your access rights. - Next you can make a copy of your page and strip it down to a minimum: one doc datasource, just a few simple fields plus a NEW edit button using the same simple action (you mentioned you had copied the button from somewhere else) - good luck

Comment: Doesn't a Simple Action in an XPage still generate code that can be viewed? I still think it's worth looking at it to assure that the copy/paste of the simple action did the right thing.

Comment: Does the button have an ID ?

Comment: Hi Clem, I have had som similar issues in the past where buttons/actions just don't do a thing. Most of the time it was a ssjs error somewhere else on the page (without reporting/logging something went wrong). The way I try to find the issue is to toggle parts of the xpage to loaded="false" and retry. Once the page works, you know where to find the reason that your button is not working.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses! Lothar, I tried what you suggested and nothing changed.  I cut down the number of fields but had the same result.  Tom, I tried that too.  Same.  The form open in an Application Layout control and I thought that might be the issue so I created a new xpage w/o it and that did work!  Not sure why at this point.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well... I really hate to admit this but I found the problem.  Before dropping the form fields into the Application Layout Control facet field, it looks like I added a panel and made the panel readonly!  .